# How to ignore non-js files with babel/register

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

When my Node app includes the routes from my App I want to ignore non-js files e.g.

```
import './scss/App.scss' // i.e via Router.js -> Routes.js -> App.js
```

At the moment Node is obviously throwing a parse error as it's trying to parse the scss as js. The babel hook currently looks like this:

```
require('babel/register')({
    stage: 0
});
```

Any ideas how I can make babel ignore them? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out it was node that needed the tweak:

```
require.extensions['.scss'] = () => {};
```

Comment: Why is he need to tweak something when it can be achieved just with correct configuration ?

Comment: That worked for me.  I just added `require.extensions['.png'] = () => {
 return;
}` below my `babel-register` statement to exclude my **.png** files that were causing the error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create `.babelrc` file and set `ignore` rule:

```
{
  "stage": 0,
  "ignore": [
    "*.scss"
  ]
}
```

You can read more about this here - https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/

Comment: Thanks, I thought about doing that too but it seems that at least when using `babel/register` and Node it doesn't have an effect

Comment: @DominicTobias you can pass the same options to `babel/register` too.

Comment: I know, I tried by passing those options to babel/register ;) One of the FB devs of babel said "Babel doesn't handle module loading and dependency management. babel/register just overloads require.extensions." -- which seems like it might work then, but I didn't have any luck so I used require.extensions directly

Answer (score 2):

You can use [babel-plugin-transform-import-ignore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-import-ignore) to ignore matched imports. All matched import statements will be removed after compilation.

```
{
  plugins: [
    [
      "babel-plugin-transform-import-ignore",
      {
        patterns: [".scss"]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```