# Skipping non-js files with @babel/register

Tags: webpack, babeljs, preact, babel-register

**Intro**

I have a task to add some new features/refactor other things in not-so-new Express + Preact 10 + Webpack 5 + Babel 7 project. And I have a problem with loading non-js file running locally for development. I've got `Syntax error` with `unexpected token at...` for non-js files.

For now, I've found that it's because @babel/register tries to read png/css/anything as a js file.

**Disclaimer**

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324435/how-to-ignore-non-js-files-with-babel-register) with an answer - use `require.extensions['.css'] = () => {};` and it works fine.

`extensions` are deprecated so it's not an option.

And, what is more important, doesn't explain why it's happening and how to fix it properly.

**The code**

I cannot give the code (company stuff) so it's a theoretical question, I'm afraid.

**I've tried**

I've tried every possible option from [Babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-register).

For SVG files I've found a library that solves this problem.

I've found a dead library for ignoring styles (css/scss etc.).

But adding a library 1) doesn't fix the problem in a complex way 2) doesn't explain why this is happening, what's wrong (or not wrong but set).

**I want to understand why and how to fix it one and for good.**

Maybe it's something I've missed? Some configuration? How does it work? Where to look for an answer?